# Can you use the effects of several berries at the same time?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the release of the second generation, new berries have been added to the game, with different effects. I am wondering if it is possible to stack the effect of a berry with the one of the others during the same Pokémon encounter?

For instance, if you use a Pinap Berry and then a Nanab Berry, will you get the effects of both berries on the Pokémon, or only the effect of the last one used (so Nanab in this particular case)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, only one berry can be used at a time during a Pokémon encounter, as mentioned in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uiwpu/gen_2_release_centralized_facts/):

> You can only use 1 berry at a time on a pokemon. So no, you can't use a razz + a nanab on a pokemon. The active berry is used as an icon on the pokemon. Once the icon disappear, on a failed catch attempt, you can use an another berry.

---

For a visual representation of what happens:

[image: pinap berry in use]

[image: can't use another berry]

Comment: I love how you're quoting a Reddit thread as an authoritative source...

Comment: @wogsland the Silph Road Reddit has been behind the majority of mechanical discoveries for Pokémon Go.

Comment: INteresting. Learn something new every day....

Answer (score 5):

No. If you use a berry and its effect is in place, the other berries in the berry carousel can't be selected until the effect has been used (i.e. the next capture attempt).